# PHP question about multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

My array looks like this:

```
Array ( [Bob] => Red [Joe] => Blue )
```

But it could be any number of people, like this:

```
Array ( [Bob] => Red [Joe] => Blue [Sam] => Orange [Carla] => Yellow)
```

Basically I want PHP to take this array and echo it so that it comes out looking like:

```
Bob - Red
Joe - Blue
Sam - Orange
Carla - Yellow
```

I know I need to loop through the array, this is what I tried:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($array); $row++) {
echo $array[0] . " - " . $array[1];
}
```

I get the following error: Undefined offset: 0, Undefined offset: 1

I realize that this doesn't work because I'm trying to use index's when the values of the array are strings.  Is there any way I can use positional index's like this with a multidimensional array that only contains strings?

Thanks

Comment: I think that's an associative array, not multidimensional...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value;
}
```

(if you want a newline, append `"\n"` to the end)

Your array is actually not *multidimensional*. An example of that would be

```
array(
    array(
        'bob',
        'tom'
    )
);
```

Note the array **within** the array.

Your array is generally called an *associative* array.

Comment: You should probably use `\n` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Without re-checking my php knowledge:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `\n` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php 
$arr = array("bob" => "red", "paul" => "blue", "preo" => "yellow", "garis" => "orange");
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ." - ".$value."<br />";
}
?>
```

Will print:

```
bob - red
paul - blue
preo - yellow
garis - orange
```

By the way, it is a `associative` array, not a `multidimensional` one, which is more something like:

```
$array[1][0][3]
```

Comment: Ah this works beautifully.  Thank you for your response, no wonder I couldn't find anything that would work -- I kept searching for multidimensional